# Can I be prompted to update related documents when something is revised

Tags: document-library, document, itemupdated

I have several instances where I have two versions of the same document (one is client facing and one in internal only). The content of the documents is identical but they are separate documents and each has it's own template. I want to ensure that when one of these documents is revised, there is a prompt to update the other document as well.

I know this can be done when you create a copy of a document, but that won't work since these are two separate documents. Is there a way to do this in this instance?

Comment: Have you considered a workflow that assigns a task whenever you update the document?

Comment: I am currently only able to work in SharePoint 2016 beta, which does not allow me to use workflows because the license has expired. A workflow could be a viable option, but I haven't worked with them so I am unfamiliar with what they can do. Could I use one to assign a task to the person who makes the changes? Also, could I specify that the workflow only runs the first time a change is made to avoid duplication in the event that the draft is checked in and out multiple times?

Comment: Yes, workflows can be quite powerful in that regard and can suit your needs well here. You can even specify that the task assignment only goes out when a document has been modified and is published, avoiding the duplicates on check-out/check-in.